# looping over variables of a data.frame leading one final data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

I have written a function to change **any one variable** (i.e., column) in a data.frame to its unique levels and return the changed data.frame.

I wonder how to change **multiple variables at once** using my function and *get one final data.frame with all the changes*?

I have tried the following, but this gives multiple data.frames while only the **last data.frame** is the **desired output**:

```
data <- data.frame(sid = c(33,33, 41), pid = c('Bob', 'Bob', 'Jim'))

#== My function for ONE variable:
f <- function(data, what){
 data[[what]] <- as.numeric(factor(data[[what]], levels = unique(data[[what]])))
 return(data)
}  

# Looping over `what`:
what <- c('sid', 'pid')
lapply(seq_along(what), function(i) f(data, what[i]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function, we could change to `return` the `data[[what]]`

```
f <- function(data, what){
   data[[what]] <- as.numeric(factor(data[[what]], levels = unique(data[[what]])))
   data[[what]]
  }  

data[what] <- lapply(seq_along(what), function(i) f(data, what[i]))
```

Or do

```
data[what] <-  lapply(what, function(x) f(data, x))
```

Or simply

```
data[what] <- lapply(what, f, data = data)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212584/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-looping-over-variables-of-a-data-frame-leading-one).